# Gigantic Kapersky AV file

Tags: anti-virus

When I ran defrag on my development workstation today I discovered an enormous file that I was unaware of that cannot be defraged.

I want to get rid of it or at least shrink it and prevent it from growing so large.
Unfortunately, my IT department is clueless.

Filename:
c:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Kaspersky Lab\AVP6\Report\eventlog.rpt

The file has 31,148 fragments and is 1.65 GB in size.

I am unable to delete the file and I do not have admin rights to stop the Kapersky process.
Without these rights I doubt that I will be able to apply any suggestions you may have.  But, I would gladly pass them on to my IT folks.

Jim

Answer (score 2):

You have two choices;

1. Talk your sysadmin guys into sorting the problem
2. Forget about it, it's not that big a deal

I'd go with option 2 unless it's making you lose sleep.

Answer (score 1):

> Filename: c:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Kaspersky Lab\AVP6\Report\eventlog.rpt

One suggestion would be to disable event logging in Kaspersky's software, and clear existing log records. (Or at least restrict them to errors and warnings.)

Another - do the above, **and** force them to upgrade; `AVP6` probably means 'Kaspersky Antivirus 6'; the latest version is 9.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this'll be the corporate version of Kaspersky Antivirus for Windows Workstations, which is up to version 6.0.4.1212. The consumer version is quite a way ahead in terms of numbers.

The 'fix' is something you should be able to do unless they've really locked down your Kaspersky GUI, the following is for version 6.0.3.837, but should be similar for the other versions.

- Click the red K in your system tray and bring up the Kaspersky Antivirus GUI.
- Click Service > Data Files.
- Click on the Files link in the reports section, it should open up the Protection dialog box.
- Change to Events tab, observe what's being logged to your Events so often
- Click the Actions button down the bottom and choose Clear All.

Should bring the reports.rpt file right down to a few kilobytes. Good Luck!

Comment: Almost four years old and still relevant! Thanks Steve!